# What kind of power supply will I need for 780 sli?

Tags: power-supply, nvidia-geforce

I have a GTX 780 and I would love to get another one and use it for sli, I was wondering what's a good powersupply wattage that I should get. I'm currently using a Corsair CX 600 Watt Power supply, and I was wondering is 600 watts is ok for 2 gtx 780's

Comment: Well it says on my 780 that you need 600 watt minimum to run.

Answer (score 2):

A standalone GTX 780 acquires power from three sources:

- PCI-e slot (75 watts max)
- PEG 6 connector from PSU (75 watts)
- PEG 8 connector from PSU (150 watts)

Based on this data the 780 is a 300 watt card when your pushing it to the max so you need 600 watts just for the SLI.

Factor in about 200 watts for the rest of your system and you should never experience issues in which your computer shuts down or fries because your PSU cannot deliver enough juice.

For more detailed power requirements it would help to know the following additional information:

- CPU make and model
- RAM size and speed
- HDD count and RPMs
- CPU cooling (air or liquid)

[Read about PEG 6 and PEG 8 and PSU power in general](http://www.enthusiastpc.net/articles/00002/3.aspx)

[PCI-e specs](https://www.pcisig.com/developers/main/training_materials/get_document?doc_id=fa4ec3357012d69821baa0856011c665ac770768)

Answer (score 0):

800 watt will be OK, 850 watt to be totally sure (if you plan to over clock).

http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/answers/id-1720218/gtx-780-sli-power-consumption.html

Otherwise 750 watt

http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/answers/id-1870878/watts-gtx-780-sli.html

Comment: Not amir, A lot* stupid autocorrect